# How to detect minecraft item (any fern) in correct item frame and in correct rotation (1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like some help in the use of command block on my adventure map. I would like to know the "execute if" command needed to detect if a fern placed at a item frame at a specific position is pointing rightways. And if it is detected emits a redstone signal

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={ItemRotation:0b,Item:{id:"minecraft:fern"}}] run say hi
```

If you want redstone output then put this command in repeating command block and place a comparator
There are 8 possible rotations

Answer (score -1):

You can select Item Frames with specific items with the NBT selector:

```
/testfor @e[type=item_frame] {Item: {id: <Insert named ID here> }}
```

---

You can test for the rotation of items in an Item Frame with the NBT selector too:

```
/testfor @e[type=item_frame] {ItemRotation: <Number that fits into a byte; number of 45 degree rotations>}
```

Alternatively, it outputs redstone power via a comparator equal to the number of rotations, being 0 is upright.

---

You can test for the orientation of an Item Frame with the NBT selector (also):

```
/testfor @e[type=item_frame] {Facing: <Direction 0-3> }
```

*Where 0 is south, 1 is west, 2 is north, and 3 is east.*

Comment: This question is for version 1.13 of minecraft. `/testfor` doesn't exist in that version.